# All my terminal applications ask me to go to the specific path (ie. /usr/sbin/iwconfig)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Just like the title says, it always asks me to go to the direct path.

ie:

`iwconfig` doesn't work. I have to type `/usr/sbin/iwconfig`

Comment: What are the contents of your PATH variable?

Comment: /home/max/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/X11
/bin
/usr/X11R6/bin
/usr/games
usr/lib/mit/bin

seems like alot? should this contain /sbin and /usr/sbin? how would I do that (do I export all of those paths at once?)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc [with an editor](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000773.htm) and write in any line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

Supposing your $PATH variable is /home/max/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/bin /usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:usr/lib/mit/bin in your case, $PATH will be appended with :/usr/sbin

To make the change happen in your current shell session write:

```
. ~/.profile
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

depending on the file you edited before.